# SCons : Need an explanation why Install not being call with scons -u

Tags: scons

There is something that I don`t understand.  See following SConscript :

```
Import('common_env')
import os
#Grab a copy of the top environment (the one sent by the SConstruct file)
common_env = common_env.Clone()
#Because this component is compiled in both win32 and win64.
if (common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] == "win32") or (common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] == "win64"):
    #Grabs the library name, the name should look like libpath_of_current_component-(debug/opt)
    libName = common_env.libName()
    common_env.USE_BOOST()

    #Grab all the sources in current dir.
    sources = Glob('*.cpp')
    #Creates the library
    myLib = common_env.Library(libName, sources)
    #Install (copy) the library in LINK/lib/winX
    common_env.Install('#/LINK/lib/' + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'], myLib)
```

If this script is invoke from his sub-folder, I have the following output :

```
scons: Entering directory `C:\svn\products\faa_mx\scons-test-speed3'
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64
cl /Fobuild\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\ThinProtocol.obj /c sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocol.cpp /TP /nologo -Od -D_DEBUG -RTC1 -MDd -Z7 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -DWINDOWS -D_MBCS -DNOMINMAX -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -W3 -nologo -GS -GR -EHa -wd4290 -wd4996 -wd4995 -TP -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 /Iinterface\asom\api /Ifwk\simulation_fwk\utils /ILINK\include /Ibuild\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64 /Isr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol /IC:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010_x64\include /Z7
ThinProtocol.cpp
cl /Fobuild\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.obj /c sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.cpp /TP /nologo -Od -D_DEBUG -RTC1 -MDd -Z7 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -DWINDOWS -D_MBCS -DNOMINMAX -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -W3 -nologo -GS -GR -EHa -wd4290 -wd4996 -wd4995 -TP -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 /Iinterface\asom\api /Ifwk\simulation_fwk\utils /ILINK\include /Ibuild\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64 /Isr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol /IC:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010_x64\include /Z7
ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.cpp
cl /Fobuild\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\ThinProtocolMessaging.obj /c sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocolMessaging.cpp /TP /nologo -Od -D_DEBUG -RTC1 -MDd -Z7 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -DWINDOWS -D_MBCS -DNOMINMAX -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -W3 -nologo -GS -GR -EHa -wd4290 -wd4996 -wd4995 -TP -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 /Iinterface\asom\api /Ifwk\simulation_fwk\utils /ILINK\include /Ibuild\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64 /Isr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol /IC:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010_x64\include /Z7
ThinProtocolMessaging.cpp
lib /nologo /OUT:build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\win64\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\ThinProtocol.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\ThinProtocolMessaging.obj
scons: `sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

As you can see, `Install` is not being call by scons at all.

If instead of calling `scons -u` from a sub-folder I call `scons` from the root, then, I have this :

```
Install file: "build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win64\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib" as "LINK\lib\win64\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib"
```

**My question is** : Why this difference? Is it because scons build system, in case of `scons -u`, knows that nobody needs the .lib, so `Install` not being called?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default set of files to be built is from the current working directory down.

You can see info on this in the manpage: http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

> A subset of a hierarchical tree may be built by remaining at the
>   top-level directory (where the SConstruct file lives) and specifying
>   the subdirectory as the target to be built:
>
> ```
> scons src/subdir
> ```
>
> or by changing directory and invoking scons with the -u option, which
>   traverses up the directory hierarchy until it finds the SConstruct
>   file, and then builds targets relatively to the current subdirectory:
>
> ```
> cd src/subdir
> scons -u .
> ```

See also this section:

> ```
> -u, --up, --search-up
> ```
>
> Walks up the directory structure until an SConstruct , Sconstruct or sconstruct file is found, and uses that as the top of the directory
>   tree. If no targets are specified on the command line, only targets at
>   or below the current directory will be built.
>
> ```
> -U
> ```
>
> Works exactly the same way as the -u option except for the way default targets are handled. When this option is used and no targets
>   are specified on the command line, all default targets that are
>   defined in the SConscript(s) in the current directory are built,
>   regardless of what directory the resultant targets end up in.

So you can either make that install a Default() target, or specify it as a dependency of some other target in the current working directory.