# Does that make sense to add libraries as source

Tags: scons

After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937541/scons-need-an-explanation-why-install-not-being-call-with-scons-u) and getting a better understanding of `scons` hiearchy, I was wondering if it is possible to tell `scons` that a target as dependency to some `lib` files.  My goal is, if a developers type `scons -u` on a sub folder, this will also compile library needed at linkage.

See my script below.  Written like this, developer has to build manually each of the `lib` before `Program` can work.

```
Import('common_env')
#Grab a copy of the top environment (the one sent by the SConstruct file)
common_env = common_env.Clone()
#Because this component is only compiled in win32.
if (common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] == "win32"):
    #Grabs the library name, the name should look like libpath_of_current_component-(debug/opt)
    libName = common_env.libName()
    progName = 'testWinRTP.exe'
    common_env.USE_BOOST()
    common_env.USE_ACE()
    common_env.USE_LOKI()
    common_env.USE_DIRECTSOUND()
    #Specific cppflag for this component (appended to the flags sent from Sconstruct)
    cppFlags = '-D_AFXDLL'
    #Specific linkFlag for this component (appended to the flags sent from SConstruct)
    linkFlags = '/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS'
    #All the libraries the binary needs.
    libSuffix = common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] + '.lib'

    common_env.Append(CPPFLAGS = cppFlags, LINKFLAGS = linkFlags)

    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/audio_fwk/src/tests/winRTP/testwinRTP/' + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_audio_fwk_src_tests_winRTP_testwinRTP-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/audio_fwk/src/tests/winRTP/CCNSMT/' + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_audio_fwk_src_tests_winRTP_CCNSMT-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/audio_fwk/src/filter_graph_mgt/'    + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_mgt-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/audio_fwk/src/filter_graph/'        + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/audio_fwk/src/filter_graph_drivers/'+ common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_drivers-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/audio_fwk/src/filter_graph_utils/'  + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_utils-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/voice_fwk/utils/src/voice_utils/'   + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_voice_utils-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/voice_fwk/utils/src/config/'        + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_config-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/voice_fwk/utils/src/log_utils/'     + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_log_utils-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS=File('#/build/'+ common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] +'/fwk/voice_fwk/utils/src/vcs_utils/'     + common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + '/libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_vcs_utils-' + libSuffix))
    common_env.Append(LIBS='msacm32.lib')
    #Sources of the library.
    sourcesLib = ['CFilterGraphTest.cpp', 'stdafx.cpp', 'testWinRTPDlg.cpp']
    #Creates the library
    common_env.Library(libName, sourcesLib)
    #Compiles a ressource file needed for the binary
    compileRes = common_env.RES('testWinRTP.rc')
    #Creates the program, notice that the sources of this program includes the .res generated by the compilation of the .rc file.
    sourcesBin = ['testWinRTP.cpp', 'testWinRTP.res']
    common_env.Program(progName, sourcesBin)
    #Install (copy) the binary in LINK/bin/winX
    common_env.installInLink(progName)
```

thx

Comment: Please also read the rest of the [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), especially chap 4 "Building and Linking with Libraries", chap 14 "Hierarchical Builds" and chap 15 "Separating Source and Build Directories". Among other things, they explain how to use the `LIBPATH` variable. What you want to do should be easy to achieve by following the guidelines from the UserGuide first.

Comment: @dirkbaechle I realized that my tree is not the same if I do `common_env.Append(CPPFLAGS = cppFlags, LINKFLAGS = linkFlags, LIBS = libList)` with `program = common_env.Program(progName, sourcesBin)` does not give same tree as `common_env.Append(CPPFLAGS = cppFlags, LINKFLAGS = linkFlags)` follow with `program = common_env.Program(progName, sourcesBin, LIBS=libList)` Which approach should we prefer?